# How to change status bar to White in MFMailComposeViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar, messageui

Pic is shown down below.

In my app, a have added an Email Prompt, but the status bar is **black** now, how can I change it to **white style**?

```
if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
            let composeMail = MFMailComposeViewController()
            composeMail.mailComposeDelegate = self
            //  configs
            composeMail.setToRecipients(["kylebing@163.com"])
            composeMail.setSubject("【饥荒口袋】反馈")
            composeMail.setMessageBody("问题页面：\n\n\n\n建议：\n", isHTML: false)
            composeMail.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.85) // Mail VC's Button Color
            // TODO: - Change status bar color
            //  show it
            self.present(composeMail, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

---

[image: Balck Status Bar - NOW]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set `statusBarStyle` in completion handler while  `present` mail controller like this

```
self.present(composeMail, animated: true, completion:{ () in
     UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
})
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: This method is deprecated in iOS 9+.

Answer (score 0):

Call this method before you present mail composer,

```
func setStatusBarBackgroundColor(color: UIColor) {

        guard let statusBar = UIApplication.shared.value(forKeyPath: "statusBarWindow.statusBar") as? UIView else { return }

        statusBar.backgroundColor = color
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

In viewWillAppear:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(animated)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = false
self.navigationController.navigationBar.opaque = false
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blueColor()}
```

**To change the status bar color of the whole application write this line of code in app delegate**

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
```

into your app delegates didFinishLoading.

Comment: I tried. Global setting of status bar does net effect MFMailComposeViewController's status bar.

Comment: @KyleBing then try to change the color in the completion block when you are presenting the view controller. You may also need to add and/or set "View controller-based status bar appearance" to NO in your Info.plist file.